# Performance of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

MyPHP Application sends a SELECT statement to MySQL with HTTPClient.

It takes about 20 seconds or more. 
I thought MySQL can’t get result immediately because MySQL Administrator shows stat for `sending data` or `copying to tmp table` while I'd been waiting for result.

But when I send same SELECT statement from another application like phpMyAdmin or jmater it takes 2 seconds or less.10 times faster!!

Dose anyone know why MySQL perform so difference?

Comment: Show us the query, and it'd also help if you could show the output of 'EXPLAIN <QUERY>' in your mysql console.

Comment: What is the query, table schema and how many rows are there in the table?

Comment: some *mystery* query (and or code) is slow, how do you think we can help you ?

Comment: Very sorry. This PHP Application has sent another tow SELECT statements.That’s why MySQL shows different performance.Vote delete to remove this post.

Answer (score 1):

Like @symcbean already said, php's mysql driver caches query results. This is also why you can do another `mysql_query()` while in a `while($row=mysql_fetch_array())` loop.

The reason MySql Administrator or phpMyAdmin shows result so fast is they append a `LIMIT 10` to your query behind your back.

If you want to get your query results fast, i can offer some tips. They involve selecting only what you need and when you need:

- Select only the columns you need, don't throw `select *` everywhere. This might bite you later when you want another column but forget to add it to `select` statement, so do this when needed (like tables with 100 columns or a million rows).
- Don't throw a 20 by 1000 table in front of your user. She cant find what she's looking for in a giant table anyway. Offer sorting and filtering. As a bonus, find out what she generally looks for and offer a way to show that records with a single click.
- With very big tables, select only primary keys of the records you need. Than retrieve additional details in the `while()` loop. This might look like illogical 'cause you make more queries but when you deal with queries involving around ~10 tables, hundreds of concurrent users, locks and query caches; things don't always make sense at first :)

These are some tips i learned from my boss and my own experince. As always, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

> Dose anyone know why MySQL perform so difference?

Because MySQL [caches query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) results, and the operating system caches disk I/O ([see this link](http://static.usenix.org/event/usenix01/full_papers/kroeger/kroeger_html/node8.html) for a description of the process in Linux)